# Google Charts - read specific columns

Tags: google-visualization, graph-visualization

I have a big CSV file with 20 columns.

In a single statement, I would like to be able to make chart one take values from column 1 to 10 and chart two to take the values from columns 11 to 20.

This way, I am only reading the CSV once, which should speed up load times.

Currently, I have the below code, which reads the same columns for both charts.

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

Thanks

```
function FwThroughputStacked(){
     $.get("../CRX1/Overall_DAB_Fortinet_Throughput_Report.csv", function(csvString) {
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);

      var options = {
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '75%'},
        explorer: {actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"]},
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        vAxis: {title: "Megabits/s", minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 10}},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 10, textStyle: {fontSize: 9} },
      };
      var options2 = {
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '75%'},
        explorer: {actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"]},
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        vAxis: {title: "Megabits/s", minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 10}},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 10, textStyle: {fontSize: 9} },
      };

     var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('throughputStacked'));

     chart.draw(view, options);
     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('throughput'));
     chart.draw(view, options2);     
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need separate views for each chart, similar to `options`

in the following snippet,
`view` is created for `chart`
-- and --
`view2` is created for `chart2`

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    $.get("output.txt", function(csvString) {
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);

      var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view2.setColumns([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]);

      var options = {
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '75%'},
        explorer: {actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"]},
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        vAxis: {title: "Megabits/s", minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 10}},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 10, textStyle: {fontSize: 9} },
      };

      var options2 = {
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '75%'},
        explorer: {actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"]},
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        vAxis: {title: "Megabits/s", minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max, textStyle: {fontSize: 10}},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 10, textStyle: {fontSize: 9} },
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('throughputStacked'));
      chart.draw(view, options);

      var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('throughput'));
      chart2.draw(view2, options2);
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I decided to use the dygraphs library instead. This was a single line of code change to get it to read certain columns :) - thank you for your input too. For some reason Stack Overflow doesn't give me any notification when someone replies!